# how to get proper formatted string?

Tags: json, python-3.x, string

if I print the string in command prompt I I'm getting it i proper structure

`"connectionstring".""."OT"."ORDERS"."SALESMAN_ID"`

but when I write it to json, I'm getting it in below format

`\"connectionstring\".\"\".\"OT\".\"ORDERS\".\"SALESMAN_ID\"`

how to remove those escape characters?

when It's happening?

Comment: Hello. Can you share your code? Thx

Comment: You should not remove them because removing them will render you JSON invalid and not readable by any JSON readers. Why do you want to remove them in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

What is happening?

Json serialization and de-serialization is happening.

From wikipedia:

In the context of data storage, serialization (or serialisation) is the process of translating data structures or object state into a format that can be stored (for example, in a file or memory buffer) or transmitted (for example, across a network connection link) and reconstructed later. [...]
The opposite operation, extracting a data structure from a series of bytes, is deserialization.

In console, you de-serialize the json but when storing in file, you serialize the json.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using json package from the standard Python lib, you can add this line

```
json.dumps(json_object, indent = 1)
```

Indentation can be chosen based on your opinion.